# Spring Integration: sending response to temp JMS queue

Tags: jms, spring-integration

I am using Spring Integrations 2.0.0 and am trying to configure the following:

An application places an object on an ActiveMQ JMS queue which is processed by the Spring-integration-driven backend. The sending application is awaiting a reply on a temporary response queue since the backend places the response in this particular queue to be consumed by this application only. The message is received and processed in the backend and the response shall be placed on the temp response queue given in the JMS request message (reply-to). In the backend the message is running through a chain of services before the response is eventually placed on the response queue.

Question: how do I configure SI to place the response to the temp queues? Is there any way that SI does this automatically or do I need to use DestinationResolver or things like that? I understood that the jms-gateway might be the right solution for this but couldn't quite figure out how to put it in place. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking to pick a message off a queue pull it though SI and send it to the JMSReplyTo, or the other way around? For the former there is <jms:inbound-gateway/> for the latter <jms:outbound-gateway/>

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring to the online documentation for SI that still points to version 1.0.x. If you instead [download the spring integration zip](http://www.springsource.com/download/community?project=Spring%20Integration) and unpack you will find the latest documentation.

What you're looking for is described in chapter 17.

If things are still unclear, then please create a documentation issue so we can tackle this for 2.0.0.RELEASE.